# MS Word 2007 - target word count

Tags: ms-word

I would like to set a daily or partial word count target in MS Word 2007?

It seems that only a total word count is displayed, or a count for selected text. But not a count which displays current words typed against a target, e.g 500 (current)/1500 (final)

thanks

Answer (score 1):

I am not aware of any method to show customized variables in the status bar, but you may include a macro to show whatever you want. Example:

```
Sub Macro1()
'
' Macro1 Macro
'
Dim WordCount As Long
Dim myRange As Range

Set myRange = ActiveDocument.Range

WordCount = 500 - myRange.ComputeStatistics(wdStatisticWords)
MsgBox WordCount & " words left"

End Sub
```

Comment: yeah, you would use belisarius' code + `Application.StatusBar` to display and hook the `DocumentChange` to recalculate word count with every change.

Comment: @Otaku yep, but I find the status bar flipping format annoying ... I can't find a way to include a user "field" on the normal status bar